# Retrieve screen coordinates in opengl and GLUT

Tags: opengl, glut

Is there a built-in function with **openGL** and **GLUT** to retrieve the **screen x and y coordinates** of a vertex in a 3D space?

I use the `currentRasterPosition` function before a `renderString` to set the raster position in the screen coordinate system. The string is renderer correctly a the vertex position.

Is it possible to get these coordinates directly usable in my program or should I necessarily use matrix operations to compute the inverse tranformation (3D coordinates to screen coordinates)?

Comment: *should I necessarily use matrix operations to compute the inverse tranformation* - that

Comment: Did [`gluProject()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluProject.xml) not work?